# How we can get the last execution time of unix shell script. ls -lu is not giving correct output.Its not in history too

Tags: bash, unix

How to get last run time of unix shell script, I tried to use ls -lu but its not showing correct output. I tried to check it in history but no luck as its old command.

Comment: If `ls -lu` is not giving you the information, you're probably stuck.   The time of use includes people reading the script to see what it does, so it's quite plausible that it isn't accurate.  Even if you had process accounting enabled, that would most likely track invocations of the shell, not the specific script.  And I'm not sure whether Linux has process accounting as was found on old UNIX systems.  It was one of the more esoteric parts of Unix.

Comment: If running the script has some sideeffects like creating or modifying files, those files and their dates might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any system logs which would be useful to get the details of last execution of script

Comment: Check this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8842/139072)

Comment: You could parse the history files for execution times.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicate, there's probably nothing in the OS that can easily help you. The simplest thing to do would be to have the script touch a file to update its mtime, then you can get the last runtime with the `stat` command. You could even get the script to touch itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "last run time was: $(stat -c '%y' "$0")"
# ... do stuff
# ...
# then set the last run time
touch "$0"
```